# Is it a bad idea to send username and password with every request from a mobile/web app to the backend api

Tags: api, security, session, passwords, token

I feel that Is it a bad idea to send username and password with every https request from a mobile/web app to the backend api but i cant come up with too many good arguments for why.

In the server, we store the hash of the password in a user record. in any case, on each request we need to load this user record from the database, for example to check if the  user was not just blacklisted. As we need to load on every request the user record, it's cost nothing to compare the passwords and in this way no need to manage another database of sessionID or tokens.

Also as the password is send in https connection, their is no way for someone in the middle to catch it. And even if someone in the middle could do it, then he can probably also do it when the user need to first login (because anyway he will need to send his password at the beginning)

So what is the good way to do ?

Comment: Am guessing that you have to save the password and username somewhere in your app to reuse on subsequent requests?

Comment: @ThankgodOssaija yes anyway i will save it somewhere in my app, I really hate some app that after 2 or 3 months because of i don't know what ask you again for my credentials (that you forget because you never really use it except for the first time)

Comment: Instead of saving the username and password on your app why not have a unique identifier that is generated and saved on each login and send back as part of login response payload. You can use this unique identifier to fetch the user from the db on subsequent request. There are UUID packages you can use for this. Or better still consider JSON web token.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This would make a great security interview question, because it measures very well the level of understanding in the security domain.

Sending username/password in each request is not advisable, but the other answer does not even touch on the real reasons why.

Technically, a username/password is **pretty much the same** as something like an API key, they are equivalent for the time they are valid. An API key is even worse in a sense, because depending on implementation, you would typically store API keys plaintext in the database, as opposed to properly hashed passwords (sidenote, but please use something like bcrypt or pbkdf2 when hashing). You are totally right, a password could be sent the same way as an API key on each request, you can revoke it the same way, etc. The API key **is** the password. There is absolutely no difference in this regard.

**However**, you should still probably not do it in most cases, for at least the following reasons.

**Passwords are weak** if chosen by users. If you have many users, many will have passwords like 123456 and similar. It will be easy to guess some of them. You don't need to run this risk in an API app, however, sending it in every request or not barely modifies this risk, but it does a little bit, because of the next point.

**Sometimes there are weaknesses in SSL/TLS.** It does happen from time to time that a new attack against TLS is disclosed, which is then patched eventually. For some time though, it may be possible for an attacker to deduce bits from an encrypted stream, which may be made easier if the encrypted content is partially known (ie. common passwords). Chances are not very high, but the problem is, with many TLS cipher suites, an attacker can record traffic now, and decrypt it later (because it takes long, or the method is not yet invented). If he only decrypts an API key that has been obsolete for 3 years, fine, but if it's a user password... Not so good.

**Server vulnerabilities** can also be a problem. A while ago there was a vulnerability in the openssl implementation where you could practically read parts of the server memory (the webserver process). If the webserver receives the user password all the time, it will be in memory probably multiple times. If it's just a temporary API key (or a session id or whatever), that's less value for the attacker. It's still good, but at least not the password.

**Internal attackers** are also something to consider. If you have an attacker already on the server, he may not be able to access the database to directly read/modify credentials, but he may be able to observe the web server process for a limited time. The same as above, it's much better if he can only observe temporary ids instead of actual passwords.

**You need to store the password on the client** if you want to send it with each request. Storing sensitive stuff on the client is not usually a good idea, opens up possibilities for an attacker. It's usually better if the user enters credentials, receives a temporary token and the client forgets about the actual password until the token expires and the user has to provide his password again. This of course may or may not be acceptable from a user experience point of view - but security is always a balance. :)

So as you can see, sending the username/password in each request is not a direct vulnerability. In fact, it may even be acceptible in many scenarios. But you can make it more secure by using temporary credentials, and why would you not, if the cost is reasonable?

Comment: thanks gabor, now at least i have one serious argument: keyword never change and are forever valid when session id are temporally. but anyway not a killer argument because if we make the validity of a session id of let say 2 hours (the norm as i understand), the attackers just need to wait that we will send again the password to obtain a new session id :(

Comment: I feel this is not going to happen "It's usually better if the user enters credentials, receives a temporary token and the client forgets about the actual password". Every time a user login then logoff (said in a shopping website), how can he forgets the actual password ?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, it is**

This is generally a terrible idea. WEP was an old network security protocol that ended up being replaced due to its intrinsic weakness to be able to get the password from a packet (beacon) without even being authenticated with the network. This is why we don't store credentials like this in transit.

**What should I do instead?**

I'd recommend using an API key. This is a private key that you can send with each request that the program can look up in the database and correlate to a particular user. For example, if a user (let's call him Bob) signs up and requests an API key, you will give him a key (e.g. `asdf12345`) the equivalent of a ticket. He can use that ticket to perform certain actions, as long as he presents his ticket each time he does something. Similar to how you can order drinks and food in a hotel's bar / restaurant and just show your room card, you'd need to show it each time you order drinks. Each time Bob performs a requests to your server, he will need to present the ticket number `asdf12345` and this will allow you to see that Bob is allowed to access these methods. Mary doesn't have a ticket, so when she requests some data, she will be denied because she does not have a token.

**How do I do this?**

Each time a user signs up for an account with your website and requests a token (and perhaps agrees to some T&Cs you have), you generate a GUID / random hash and store it in a `dbo.ApiKeys` table which should contain both the API key and a UserId. The user's application should add this key so that any time it performs an API request, they can include this token. This prevents you from giving up user's credentials in each request. It also means that if a user manages to have their API key compromised by whatever means, it's generally their fault (they were in starbucks on an insecure connection, they had it saved in a .txt file on their desktop, they wrote it on a sticky note on their desk etc.)

**EDIT: The OWASP Standards**

If you're interested in further reading and would like to know the industry standard for this, OWASP has [a page dedicated to this](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet) particular task. They are the universal go-to wiki for best practises in computer security.

Comment: thanks horkrine, but you way is much more complicated and it's not show why the way of sending the password in every request is worse (except if we say that https is weak). because in theory noone can access the password send via https, even if we send it on each request

Comment: Whilst that is true, you are then relying on HTTPS to secure your users. Not all users will be aware of what HTTPS even is, let alone whether or not they are currently connected through it. By allowing your application to use private keys instead, it means you can easily manage these keys. You can also revoke the API key if the client violates the usage agreement, and return a Http response 429 "Too Many Requests" HTTP response code if requests are coming in too quickly. Seriously, read the article - It has a lot of useful information in it that might help you out

Comment: As it's an mobile app, all the connection are made in the background and the user don't know anything about it. With login/password send on every request i can also block the client if DOS attack in the same way as you will do with api key (simply put the user record to inactive)  ...

Comment: Should the API key have an expiration date?

Answer (score 0):

To respond to your question why credentials should not be included in every request and response. This will ensure that malicious apps will not be able to intercept the data and compromise user credentials.

Once you include credentials in every request it means that you are obviously storing them somewhere in the app which can be reverse engineered and compromised should the user loose his or her device.

Answer (score 0):

The detailed answers cover it, but i think the key points can be expressed more simply:

Provided its a secure protocol (HTTPS) it's not wrong to send the login credentials on each request.

However, unless you plan for an unusable user experience (prompt user to enter username and password on each request), your question implies you would be storing the password on disk in your app data (which you confirm in your comments).  That is the problem, as it makes your app an target for hackers looking to steal passwords.

This is why tokens are used instead.